# How to run PHP files on aws s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-rds

I have developed my website on aws platform using aws s3 buckets.How do I run php files on my domain?

Comment: S3 is a object storage, it doesn't run anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

S3 doesn't run any sort of CGI script (PHP, Perl, Ruby, etc). Think of it as a static html and image repository.

If you want to host your PHP application on AWS, consider using AWS Beanstalk. It will launch an environment (server, IP, etc) where you can deploy and run your PHP application easily.

Comment: Happy to help. If you end up using Beanstalk, note that there a couple oddities around the health monitoring. We just did a blog post that will help you get acquainted. https://www.bluematador.com/blog/aws-elastic-beanstalk-health-and-metric-monitoring

Comment: Ok is there any cheaper approach to host dynamic website? Because Beanstalk caused me heaps of data

Comment: here's a cheap list: https://www.hostingadvice.com/reviews/cheap/

You can also just start a t2.micro on EC2 - it's on the free tier, and can save some money.

Alternatively, and it only works for certain use cases, you could try Jekyll. Not knowing what you need for a website, it may not work, but I love it, and want to promote it more (no affiliation).