# Getting "SignatureDoesNotMatch" while submitting a form using php in my static website on s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My website is hosted on s3 and served through a CloudFront distribution through HTTPS.
an email to a specific address with basic info fields like name email and text.
A few days ago it stopped working and now I am getting the following error whenever I try

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>ASIA4OY4SXX6QO7ZXVHR</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20231010T123140Z 20231010/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request 6f731b82a6d07a099b19ecc3de5cd8be10f31bb8842359c205c6f6025cee138b</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>90cb1fa85ea52b194e15e181d25566c2fdb2de130effe2e7fb71a1ac5df92cc2</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 33 31 30 31 30 54 31 32 33 31 34 30 5a 0a 32 30 32 33 31 30 31 30 2f 75 73 2d 65 61 73 74 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 36 66 37 33 31 62 38 32 61 36 64 30 37 61 30 39 39 62 31 39 65 63 63 33 64 65 35 63 64 38 62 65 31 30 66 33 31 62 62 38 38 34 32 33 35 39 63 32 30 35 63 36 66 36 30 32 35 63 65 65 31 33 38 62</StringToSignBytes>
<CanonicalRequest>POST /send.php email=test%40gmail.com&name=test&phone=28287 host:3psync-web.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD x-amz-date:20231010T123140Z x-amz-security-token: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 x-amz-source-account:181119001231 x-amz-source-arn:arn:aws:cloudfront::181119001231:distribution/EJ7CZPX9K219J host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-source-account;x-amz-source-arn UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
<CanonicalRequestBytes>50 4f 53 54 0a 2f 73 65 6e 64 2e 70 68 70 0a 65 6d 61 69 6c 3d 68 73 61 64 69 61 35 33 38 25 34 30 67 6d 61 69 6c 2e 63 6f 6d 26 6e 61 6d 65 3d 48 61 6c 65 65 6d 61 26 70 68 6f 6e 65 3d 32 38 32 38 37 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 33 70 73 79 6e 63 2d 77 65 62 2e 73 33 2e 75 73 2d 65 61 73 74 2d 31 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 3a 32 30 32 33 31 30 31 30 54 31 32 33 31 34 30 5a 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2d 74 6f 6b 65 6e 3a 49 51 6f 4a 62 33 4a 70 5a 32 6c 75 58 32 56 6a 45 4d 76 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 77 45 61 43 57 56 31 4c 58 64 6c 63 33 51 74 4d 53 4a 48 4d 45 55 43 49 51 44 53 5a 53 53 77 55 46 6a 35 4d 34 30 50 64 33 6b 4d 39 6d 48 59 38 64 79 75 69 65 46 30 35 78 39 69 79 7a 38 51 55 43 66 6b 30 51 49 67 58 68 31 4a 57 68 50 39 2b 69 68 4f 69 58 35 50 76 73 2b 6f 47 42 62 4b 58 49 62 5a 54 42 37 6b 42 41 78 2b 77 2b 58 64 42 69 59 71 76 67 49 49 31 50 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 41 52 41 41 47 67 77 34 4e 54 59 7a 4e 6a 6b 77 4e 54 4d 78 4f 44 45 69 44 43 58 34 35 59 4a 65 57 4d 66 39 75 76 34 5a 36 69 71 53 41 6f 4b 6c 4e 6f 44 63 70 4c 55 4c 79 51 63 78 73 37 45 6c 61 41 47 47 46 69 62 43 65 2f 75 37 4a 72 67 75 79 64 62 34 6d 33 36 6e 48 6b 43 35 39 70 46 5a 4e 38 64 2f 30 4e 49 57 6c 4b 79 46 55 4b 68 62 4d 6b 38 35 58 53 42 6f 42 61 4a 46 78 78 41 66 43 7a 59 75 44 44 79 31 47 74 7a 56 36 70 4f 5a 6a 4c 74 73 4e 35 52 70 6a 76 77 2b 69 49 74 79 76 4f 42 4b 65 71 36 66 64 4b 69 66 6c 65 41 53 67 56 5a 4a 79 44 6a 30 74 79 62 59 6e 76 2b 71 70 52 76 45 50 50 79 6c 42 38 72 58 6e 6c 56 55 52 2f 42 65 69 7a 68 67 55 52 76 73 33 6e 77 72 6b 37 2b 30 32 67 37 44 33 41 6d 4f 4a 37 33 56 5a 50 6a 35 63 66 64 42 65 32 51 67 42 4e 6c 4e 67 77 6f 2f 4f 66 6f 65 4a 79 70 2b 6e 68 65 31 6f 70 67 74 62 4a 46 47 31 57 43 33 59 48 58 4b 52 4e 31 2f 67 61 55 73 6f 7a 65 75 2f 32 46 31 43 77 4a 39 70 47 48 69 70 77 68 46 77 77 4c 63 2b 49 45 50 33 6e 70 51 4e 61 4c 79 56 33 47 75 70 66 75 37 42 44 4c 57 78 7a 73 53 58 6f 73 6f 4b 39 44 6d 52 42 61 39 61 50 4f 4e 41 77 6c 70 71 51 58 72 45 47 51 4d 37 75 32 30 75 32 42 56 75 64 38 6b 49 37 48 38 6e 6e 54 64 49 6d 35 59 2b 79 69 78 44 45 4a 4a 7a 43 45 77 76 64 36 55 71 51 59 36 6a 77 45 77 6c 37 46 59 38 6d 2f 55 4e 65 5a 36 78 4c 7a 32 6f 2b 57 47 42 59 4f 74 4f 54 6b 49 2f 43 54 55 47 63 68 5a 43 32 39 45 43 76 2b 44 46 67 4f 67 77 71 48 4a 36 78 34 44 64 55 70 4b 4b 37 50 79 38 4e 66 4a 72 34 66 7a 38 50 71 35 38 70 73 73 56 34 46 37 74 36 4d 51 6c 53 71 65 46 32 6c 72 59 53 57 6c 39 74 65 47 2b 78 62 64 4c 6f 6e 4c 2b 4d 35 62 2f 71 68 42 4a 30 69 62 73 72 4d 6a 2b 51 41 50 68 39 2f 47 33 37 4e 63 36 78 2b 50 4b 2b 42 44 51 4c 4b 6b 68 31 6c 6f 4c 33 45 52 58 69 6c 52 70 2f 4d 43 63 42 51 6c 68 67 34 66 71 76 6b 42 31 6f 4c 36 39 48 4c 67 70 41 3d 3d 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 6f 75 72 63 65 2d 61 63 63 6f 75 6e 74 3a 31 38 31 31 31 39 30 30 31 32 33 31 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 6f 75 72 63 65 2d 61 72 6e 3a 61 72 6e 3a 61 77 73 3a 63 6c 6f 75 64 66 72 6f 6e 74 3a 3a 31 38 31 31 31 39 30 30 31 32 33 31 3a 64 69 73 74 72 69 62 75 74 69 6f 6e 2f 45 4a 37 43 5a 50 58 39 4b 32 31 39 4a 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2d 74 6f 6b 65 6e 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 6f 75 72 63 65 2d 61 63 63 6f 75 6e 74 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 6f 75 72 63 65 2d 61 72 6e 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes>
<RequestId>0BTFDEJ81PQ0DJPZ</RequestId>
<HostId>XrFPn+rkcSaqjD3vRKQeu8TmJNzSA78PH5daVBZLyyDk9tZ/1VuDcC0DOjvkiFU9VEywMlgwDZpp3Yznsnj3ow==</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have tried several thread online but all of them mainly point to using incorrect keys or request format. I am not using the aws sdk at all in my code and its basic function using php **mail** function:

```
$to = "test@gmail.com";$subject = "Sign-Up";$headers = 'From: '.$email . "\r\n" ."MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ."Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
    mail($to,  $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "thankyou.html";</script>';
}
else
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.");</script>';
}}
else
{   echo $error;
}
```

Comment: We can't see any of your code that actually makes a request to S3.

Comment: My code doesn't make a request to s3. The website code is hosted on s3. I am using the PHP mail function that allows me to send mail directly from the script. it's not linked with s3 or was. reference https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: Error doesn't sound much as if it had actually anything to do with sending the mail ... Does your code even get to that part? To me this more looks like your POST request itself was rejected already for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this problem. After digging in for a day I found that it's impossible to do such processing on a static website on s3 which makes sense.
I resolved this by making a lambda function on AWS to send emails and calling it within a client-side JS on my website. Everything is working now.

Reference: [How to run PHP files on aws s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392688/how-to-run-php-files-on-aws-s3-bucket)